# Gulp protractor can run test while protractor protractor.conf.js gives errors

Tags: gulp, protractor

I am using a spring boot application. It has gulp. While the app is up, i go to directory which has

```
      vegan@vegan:~/hb-xx/gateway$ ls
    bower.json  gateway.iml  gulp  gulpfile.js 
 logs  mvnw  mvnw.cmd  node_modules  package.json  pom.xml  README.md  src  target
```

and run this command to run e2e tst

```
vegan@vegan:~/hb-xx/gateway$ gulp protractor
[21:35:55] Using gulpfile ~/hb-xx/gateway/gulpfile.js
[21:35:55] Starting 'protractor'...
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
..


2 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 23.814 seconds
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 passed
[21:36:20] Finished 'protractor' after 24 s
```

It runs tests well.

But i dont want to make app up for every time i want to run tests so i downloaded protractor to my local machine to run it manually.

So i go directory where `conf` is:

```
vegan@vegan:~/hb-xx/gateway/src/test/javascript$ ls
e2e  karma.conf.js  protractor.conf.js  spec  testcaner
```

then run test:

```
vegan@vegan:~/hb-xx/gateway/src/test/javascript$ protractor protractor.conf.js 
[21:36:24] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[21:36:24] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
FF

Failures:
1) Login module should fail to login with wrong password
  Message:
    Failed: WebElementCondition did not resolve to a WebElement: [object Object]
  Stack:
    TypeError: WebElementCondition did not resolve to a WebElement: [object Object]
        at TypeError (native)
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:722:17
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: Run it("should fail to login with wrong password") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:79:14)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/vegan/hb-xx/gateway/src/test/javascript/e2e/account/login/loginControllerSpec.js:13:9)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vegan/hb-xx/gateway/src/test/javascript/e2e/account/login/loginControllerSpec.js:8:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)

2) Login module should be able to login as a cta
  Message:
    Failed: WebElementCondition did not resolve to a WebElement: [object Object]
  Stack:
    TypeError: WebElementCondition did not resolve to a WebElement: [object Object]
        at TypeError (native)
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:722:17
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: Run it("should be able to login as a cta") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:79:14)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/vegan/hb-xx/gateway/src/test/javascript/e2e/account/login/loginControllerSpec.js:26:9)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vegan/hb-xx/gateway/src/test/javascript/e2e/account/login/loginControllerSpec.js:8:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)

2 specs, 2 failures
Finished in 17.017 seconds

[21:36:42] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[21:36:42] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 2 test(s)
[21:36:42] I/launcher - overall: 2 failed spec(s)
[21:36:42] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

i have 2 small classes

```
'use strict';

var LoginPageObject = require('./loginControllerPageObject');

describe(
    'Login module', function () {

        var loginPageObject = new LoginPageObject();

        it(
            'should fail to login with wrong password', function () {


               loginPageObject.login('wrong','123');
                expect(
                    loginPageObject.loginTextLocator.getText()
                ).toMatch(loginPageObject.loginText);

            }
        );


        it(
            'should be able to login as a admin', function () {

                loginPageObject.login('admin','asd-**326SMmasdsa);


            }
        );

    }
);
```

and other class

```
'use strict';

var CommonPageObject = require('../commonPageObject');

var LoginPageObject = function() {

    var commonPageObject = new CommonPageObject();


    this.login = element(by.css('[data-menu-item="login"]'));
    this.username = element(by.model('vm.model.username'));
    this.password = element(by.model('vm.model.password'));
    this.loginButton = element(by.css('[aria-label="login.button"]'));

    this.loginTextLocator = element(by.css('[class="md-headline ng-scope"]'));
    this.loginText = /Giriş/;

    this.baseUrl=commonPageObject.baseUrl;



    this.login = function(name,password) {

        this.get();
        browser.driver.wait(protractor.until
            .elementIsVisible(element(by.css('header'))));

        this.setName(name);
        this.setPassword(password);

        this.loginButton.click();
    };



    this.get = function() {
        browser.get(commonPageObject.baseUrl+'/#account/login');
    };


    this.setName = function(name) {
        this.username.clear().sendKeys(name);
    };

    this.setPassword = function(password) {
        this.password.clear().sendKeys(password);

    };

};

module.exports = LoginPageObject;
```

and other class

```
'use strict';

var CommonPageObject = function() {

    this.baseUrl = "http://xxx:8080";//i am changing this to another website while not using local
};

module.exports = CommonPageObject;
```

i tried this

changed `protractor.until` to browser.until or driver.until

```
this.get();
browser.driver.wait(protractor.until
    .elementIsVisible(element(by.css('header'))));
```

but

gives error for

```
essage:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'elementIsVisible' of undefined
  Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'elementIsVisible' of undefined
        at null.login (/home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/src/test/javascript/e2e/account/login/loginControllerPageObject.js:29:13)



   this lien
.elementIsVisible(element(by.css('header'))));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, if you run your tests with `protractor` directly, your app is not served and, hence, the tests fail. The reason they fail this way is because you are using the webdriver's `browser.driver.wait()`, but using the protractor's expected condition. Replace:

```
browser.driver.wait(protractor.until
   .elementIsVisible(element(by.css('header'))));
```

with:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('header')));
```

Also see this related issue:

- [WebElementCondition did not resolve to a WebElement](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3201)